# just see the picture please issue is my seekbar thumb showing its initial view despite i am seeking it

Tags: android, xml

[image]

> having issue all my seekbars even any view showing its initial value as well on runtime i ma inflaiting framgent class from activity and initilize its views working fine but having issues on views prints or initial value still there even with ony of them like seek bar edit text hints showing even i am writing someting there 
>   FragmentClass

```
`override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.volumefragment, container,
            false)
        Ringervolume = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.seekBar) as SeekBar
        alarmvolume = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.seekBar1) as SeekBar
        vibrationset = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.seekBar2) as SeekBar
        donotdistrub = v
iew.findViewById<View>(R.id.switch1) as Switch
        silentmode = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.switch2) as Switch
        musicvolume = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.seekBar4) as SeekBar
```

> MainActivity

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))

        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val fragment = VolumeFagment()
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
 getSupportActionBar()!!.setTitle("Sounds")
```

> Fragment_xml
>   this is xml file i dont think so there is any issue in xml file but it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@null"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/volumedownimg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vibrationimg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar2" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vibrationimg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar2" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"

        android:splitTrack="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vibrationimg2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar1" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:splitTrack="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:background="#FF0000FF"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar1"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"

        android:background="#FF0000FF"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"

        android:splitTrack="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/alarmimg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/volumedownimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/outline_volume_off_black_18dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vibrationimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/alarmimg"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/outline_volume_off_black_18dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vibrationimg2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vibrationimg"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/outline_volume_off_black_18dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/alarmimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/volumedownimg"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/outline_volume_off_black_18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Ring Volume"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:text="Media Volume"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.387" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:text="Alarm Volume"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.258" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Music  Volume"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Do Not Distrub"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26999998" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Also vibrate for calls"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="phone ringtone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar6" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Profile"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem, Can you please clear?

Comment: just see the picture please issue is my seekbar thumb showing its initial value despite i am seeking it

Comment: seekbar is working fine it happen with other views aswell